# Is it possible to create an identity column in Oracle without it being a primary key, and how does it relate to H2 Database?

Tags: sql, oracle, h2

I'm trying to transform a table to start using natural keys instead of surrogate keys, so before explaining what I'm trying to do, I'll explain how the database is currently set up.

```
-- FOO_BAR TABLE
id NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY, -- A sequence and a trigger is set up to this column.
uuid CHAR(36) UNIQUE
```

What I'm trying to do is:

1. The `id` column should be deleted;
2. The `uuid` column should be the primary key;
3. A new column called `creation_order` should be created, and it should have the same values as `id`, but it'll not be the primary key.

So after the migration the table should look like this:

```
-- FOO_BAR TABLE
creation_order NUMBER(10) UNIQUE GENERATED AS IDENTITY,
uuid CHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY
```

The problem that made me create this question is that I'm using H2, and I should try to create the migration scripts the most pure SQL compliant as Oracle allows me, and since `GENERATED AS IDENTITY` is pure SQL and it's now supported by Oracle DB, I should try to stick with that.

---

So, my first question is:

In H2, I can't follow this approach, as `GENERATED AS IDENTITY` will always implicitly create a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint, as pointed in [H2 Database Documentation](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#column_definition):

> Identity and auto-increment columns are columns with a sequence as the default. The column declared as the identity columns is implicitly the primary key column of this table (unlike auto-increment columns).

So for H2, I need to use `AUTO_INCREMENT` instead.

I looked for the [documentation of Oracle DB](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF55657) and I didn't find any information about primary keys for the identity type, does it mean that Oracle's `GENERATED AS IDENTITY` work just as H2's `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

And if the answer is positive and `GENERATED AS IDENTITY` is different for each database, does anyone have any idea of how to use the same migration script for both databases, or is it impossible?

Thank you!

Comment: "*how to use the same migration script for both databases*" use Liquibase with its "naive" XML format (not "plain SQL"). Define the column as `autoincrement` and Liquibase will do the right thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible (Oracle 12c):

```
CREATE TABLE tab (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  some_identity  NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,  -- it is not PK
  descr VARCHAR2(30)
);
```

or with `DEFAULT`:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq;

CREATE TABLE tab(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY
   ,some_identity NUMBER DEFAULT seq.NEXTVAL
   ,descr VARCHAR2(30)
);
```

Comment: Thank you, but that answer only part of my question.

Comment: @MagnoNascimento: that's the reason why you should only ask one question per question.

Comment: H2 is a totally different database compared to Oracle.

Comment: @TheImpaler, but I'm using H2 in Oracle mode, if they're not the same, could it be considered a bug?

Comment: The "H2 Oracle mode" share *some* similarities with Oracle but just a few ones. It doesn't -- by any mean -- to emulate Oracle. Oracle has a ton of features that you should NOT expect to see in H2. They behave quite differently. Why do you need this in the first place? If you want full Oracle compatibility, then just install Oracle locally, or on the web. They are free.

Comment: @TheImpaler, there's a huge project I'm working on, where H2 is being used on Oracle mode for testing, while we use Oracle for production, that's why we (including my boss) want to know a common approach for both of doing this, and maybe, if possible, something closer to pure SQL.

Comment: This is a [very] personal advise: Use Oracle, it's free for development. I've seen your strategy implemented by one my dearest friends. After a couple of years, he gave up. Those two databases are so different your strategy only works for CRUD-grade SQL, not even pure SQL, but limited to SQL from the 1990s. If you need performance or any feature from the 2000s then this strategy doesn't fly. For exampe, need CTEs? Not available in H2. Window functions? Nope. Constraint deferrability? Nope; Lateral joins? No. Indexes on expressions? Nope. Partial indexes? Nope. Clustering indexes? Not either.

Comment: This doesn't answer completely my question, but it provides me enough information to go ahead and question the devs about how it should work, so I'll accept it.

The ticket I opened on H2 is here: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/1437

Thank you!

Comment: Just updating, the ticket I created for H2 is already resolved and merged, and it'll probably be present on the next release. Thank you for your support!